# User defined function to emulate Max.ifs in VBA 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function to calculate the maximum of a range based on 2 criteria, just like Excel's 2016 function (MAX.IFS) do, as far as I know I am doing it ok but it returns #VALUE error.

Could you help me?

```
Option Base 1
Function MaxIf(RangoUno As Range, RangoDos As Range, RangoTres As Range, RUno As Variant, RDos As Variant) As Variant
Dim x() As Variant, y() As Variant, z() As Long, w() As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ConstraintUno As Variant, ConstraintDos As Variant, k As Long
i = 1
k = 0
ConstraintUno = RUno
ConstraintDos = RDos
 x = RangoUno 'Rango que contiene la primera restricción
 y = RangoDos  'Rango que contiene la segunda restricción
 z = RangoTres 'Rango que contiene los valores numericos
  For i = 1 To RangoUno.Rows.Count
   If x(i, 1) = RUno Then
    If y(i, 1) = RDos Then
    k = k + 1
    ReDim Preserve w(k, 1)
     w(k, 1) = z(i, 1) ' w() es una matriz que almacena los valores numericos en cuya fila cumpla con las rectricciones 1 y 2
      End If
    End If
   Next i
MaxIf = application.max(w)
End Function
```

Comment: You can't `ReDim Preserve w(k, 1)`.  Only the highest dimension can change with `ReDim Preserve`.  Since you only use 1 for the upper dimension, just transpose the arrays.

Comment: You could get rid of the dimensions of `w` entirely by just making it a `Long` instead of an array of `Long`, initialising it to `-2,147,483,648` and then using `If z(i, 1) > w Then w = z(i, 1)`.  That then gets rid of the need for `Application.Max` too.  (But I don't like the fact that `w` is declared to be a `Long` anyway - it will undoubtedly confuse people who use the function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to fix the code:

1) Change `z() as long` into `z() as Variant`

2) You cannot `redim w` the way you are doing (with a 2D array). However, you can avoid this headache by making `w` a single-dimension array, since you are simply keeping simple values in it in order to call `Application.Max`...

```
 ReDim Preserve w(k)
 w(k) = z(i, 1)
 ....
 MaxIf = application.max(w)
```

The UDF worked well for me after these changes.